# Take date of input and enter it as the minDate of the Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following input:

```
<input type="hidden" class="old_ship_date" name="old_ship_date" value="<?php echo esc_attr( substr( $current_date, 0, 10 ) ); ?>">
```

The date within that input is "yyyy-mm-dd".

I want to take that date and enter it into the `minDate` option of the datepicker. Is there a way I can just enter a date?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var now = new Date();
    $('#mypicker').datepicker({
    //options
    dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    minDate: $('.old_ship_date').val(),
    firstDay: 0,
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $('.new_ship_date').val('');
        $('.new_ship_date').val(dateText);
    },
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var now = new Date();

  var dt =  $('.old_ship_date').val();
  $('#mypicker').datepicker({
    //options
    dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date(dt),
    firstDay: 0,
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      $('.new_ship_date').val('');
      $('.new_ship_date').val(dateText);
    },
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the hidden input really necessary?

Then:

1. The `minDate` has to be a date object.
2. To ensure there will be no timezone issue often weirdly subtracting 1 day... It is necessary to specify the time too. So add `00:00:00` to the date...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#mypicker').datepicker({
    //options
    dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date("<?php echo esc_attr( substr( $current_date, 0, 10 ) ); ?> 00:00:00"),
    firstDay: 0,
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $('.new_ship_date').val('');
        $('.new_ship_date').val(dateText);
    },
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
  });
});
```